# "Chapters" missing in PhpStorm "Search Everywhere"

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use PhpStorm for many years and for all this time the search results for "Search Everywhere" were separated in "Chapters" for Classes, Files, Actions and so on, as its shown in this screenshot (from the internet).

[image: PhpStorm search everywhere with chapters]

But recently I noticed that these "chapters" are gone and everything is just mixed together without any separation.

[image: PhpStorm without chapters]

Now its very difficult for me to find what I'm looking for. I searched everywhere in the settings but couldn't find any options to bring back those chapters.

Am I missing something or is this feature just gone?
I'm using PhpStorm 2020.3.2.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: These "chapters" are tabs now. You can see that by comparing your screenshots: see the "Classes", "Files" & "Symbols" parts. They are tabs now.

Comment: @Dmitrii Not exactly. 2020.2 or so seem to had those dividers present when `All` tab was selected ("chapters"). E.g. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/searching-everywhere.html

Comment: @LazyOne ah yes, indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The behavior can be enabled back by disabling `search.everywhere.mixed.results` in Registry. To access it open Help > Find Action and type "Registry".